# Median/average does not return the right values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTb7Z.png)

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following:
if(cell A1 is found in list 1), for each row in which it's found and `if(C4:C10 > B4:B10)`, then `median(the subtraction between C and B values, for every row that has text1)`.

I've tried two 2 different formulas:

1 - `{=MEDIAN(IF(AND((C4:C10>B4:B10);(B4:B10=A1));(C4:C10-B4:B10)))}`

2 - `{=MEDIAN((C4:C10>B4:B10)*(B4:B10=A1)*(C4:C10-B4:B10))}`

For median it always returns 0 and for the average really small values that aren't accurate. I'm sure the median and the averages aren't correct.

What would the problem be?

Also, how would I use something like:
`{=MEDIAN((C4:C10>B4:B10)*(B4:B10=A1)*(C4:C10-B4:B10))}`

If one the columns had text in some rows? (which isn't the case for the former problem, but it has arisen before).

```
text1                   

list 1      list 2      list 3
text2       1           5
text4       2           4
text1       4           6
text4       1           6
text1       4           5
text4       2           4
text1       3           3
```

Comment: but in your example, none of the values in C are bigger than those in B. Am I missing something? it doesn't meet your second criteria!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `AND` function in these type of formulas because `AND` returns a single result (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) not an array as required.

Your second formula is closer but by multiplying all the conditions you will get zeroes for every row where the conditions are not met, hence skewing the results.

You can use either one of these similar versions:

`=MEDIAN(IF((C4:C10>B4:B10)*(A4:A10=A1);C4:C10-B4:B10))`

`=MEDIAN(IF(C4:C10>B4:B10;IF(A4:A10=A1;C4:C10-B4:B10)))`

both need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

To handle text in columns `B` or `C` (and to make the formula ignore those rows but work otherwise) you can add an extra `IF` function like this

`=MEDIAN(IF(C4:C10>B4:B10;IF(A4:A10=A1;IF(ISNUMBER(C4:C10-B4:B10);C4:C10-B4:B10))))`

All formulas will work equally well with `AVERAGE` function in place of `MEDIAN`

Another way to get the `MEDIAN` while ignoring text is to use `AGGREGATE` function like this:

`=AGGREGATE(17;6;C4:C10-B4:B10/(C4:C10>B4:B10)/(A4:A10=A1);2)`

That doesn't need "array entry" but will only work in `Excel 2010` or later versions. There's no simple equivalent for `AVERAGE`

`17` denotes `QUARTILE` function - second quartile is the equivalent of median

See attached screenshot demonstrating the last two formulas with your sample data....and some added text

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: aren't you confusing column B with Column A? Column A contains the text values that need to match **A1** and not the column B. Hence in your formula they should be replaced with **A4:A10=A1**

Comment: I'm just using the same cell references used in the formulas in the question

Comment: yes, but the formulae in the question are wrong! it is a mistake in the source text of the question. It should be corrected. Besides, a cell can't have a text value to be matched with that of A1 and also at the same time be subtracted!

Comment: Worked great, thank you for the great detailed explanation! I basically had to merge the two functions I had tried, it seems, ahah

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the values in `column C` that is **list 3** are bigger than those in `column B` that is **list 2**, then you can use the following formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((A4:A10=A1)*(C4:C10>B4:B10);C4:C10-B4:B10))
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.
tell me if it doesn't work.